# resizing the created partions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

i have attached the screen shots of Gparted. @heynnema
I have a 750GB sata hard drive. I have installed Ubuntu using the option "Erase everything on the drive and install Ubuntu". Now the installation is completed and I have a big partition of almost 745Gb.

```
size: 745 GB — 722 GB free (3.2% full)
device: /dev/sda2
partition type: Linux Filesystem
Content: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root
```

There's also a swap partition:

```
size: 4.2 GB (4,220,518,400 bytes)
device: /dev/sda3
partition type: Linux Swap
Content: Swap (version 1) — Active
```

I don't know whether Ubuntu is installed in it or not. I want from the remaining 722GB, 600GB to create two or three different partitions.

Can I make these new partitions in such a way that in future if I want to install Windows for a dual-boot it will be possible to do so?[**The screen shot of gparted are attacted in the link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ruww.png)

Comment: Of course it is possible. Boot a live CD and resize your ubuntu partition with gparted and hit apply changes. Then create new partitions -> apply changes. SEe http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Comment: Taj... please see my answer in your original question. You can delete this duplicate if you like.